# Jetpack Compose How to pass arguments between screens with Hilt ViewModel using savedStateHandle?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

Recently in my app I've been using simple navigation component arguments passing. Since I've added Hilt ViewModel, i came across something called *saveStateHandle* and apparently I can pass arguments between screens easly with this. How can i do that? I implemented the code in my *HiltViewModel*

```
@HiltViewModel
class ExerciseViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val repository: ExerciseRepository,
savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

val data: MutableState<DataOrException<List<Exercise>, Boolean, Exception>> =
    mutableStateOf(
        DataOrException(null, true, Exception(""))
    )

val muscleGroup: String? = savedStateHandle[Constants.MUSCLE_GROUP_KEY]

private val _exerciseListFromDb = MutableStateFlow<List<Exercise>>(emptyList())
val exerciseListFromDb = _exerciseListFromDb.asStateFlow()

init {
    getExercises()

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.getAllExercisesFromDb().collect() {
            _exerciseListFromDb.value = it
        }
    }
}

private fun getExercises() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        data.value.loading = true
        data.value = repository.getExercises()

        if (data.value.data.toString().isNotEmpty())
            data.value.loading = false
    }
}

fun insertExerciseToDb(exercise: Exercise) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.insertExerciseToDb(exercise)
}

fun deleteExerciseFromDb(exercise: Exercise) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.deleteExerciseFromDb(exercise)
}
```

}

I want to pass *muscleGroup* parameter between screens *HomeScreen* -> *SampleExercisesScreen*. How do I send parameter from *HomeScreen* to HiltViewModel *ExerciseViewModel* and then use it in *SampleExercisesScreen* and other screens?

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController) {

Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
color = AppColors.mBackground) {

    Column {
        Header()

        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 50.dp)){

            MuscleButton(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), icon = R.drawable.body, muscleGroup = "Chest", navController)
            MuscleButton(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), icon = R.drawable.male, muscleGroup = "Back", navController)
            MuscleButton(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), icon = R.drawable.shoulder, muscleGroup = "Shoulders", navController)

        }

        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()){

            MuscleButton(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), icon = R.drawable.muscle, muscleGroup = "Biceps", navController)
            MuscleButton(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), icon = R.drawable.triceps, muscleGroup = "Triceps", navController)
            MuscleButton(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), icon = R.drawable.leg, muscleGroup = "Legs", navController)

        }

    }

}
```

},

```
@Composable
fun SampleExerciseScreen(navController: NavController, muscleGroup: String, exerciseList: List<Exercise>?) {

val mExerciseList = exerciseList!!.filter { it.muscle == muscleGroup }
Log.d("TEST", "$mExerciseList, $muscleGroup")

Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
color = AppColors.mBackground) {

    Column {

        MyTopBar(navController = navController)

        LazyColumn(Modifier.weight(1f)){
            
            items(mExerciseList) {
                ExerciseRow(exercise = it)
            }
            
        }
        GoToButton(navController = navController, text = "YOUR EXERCISES", route = Screen.UserExercises.passMuscleGroup(muscleGroup))
    }
}
```

}
*NavGraph*

```
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController, viewModel: ExerciseViewModel) {

val exerciseList = viewModel.data.value.data?.toList()

val exerciseListFromDb = viewModel.exerciseListFromDb.collectAsState().value
val muscleGroup = viewModel.muscleGroup

NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.Home.route) {

    composable(
        route = Screen.Home.route
    ) {
        HomeScreen(navController = navController)
    }

    composable(
        route = Screen.SampleExercise.route,
    ) {
        SampleExerciseScreen(
            navController = navController,
            muscleGroup = muscleGroup.toString(),
            exerciseList = exerciseList
        )
    }

    composable(
        route = Screen.UserExercises.route,
        arguments = listOf(navArgument(MUSCLE_GROUP_KEY) {
            type = NavType.StringType
        })
    ) {
        UserExercisesScreen(
            navController = navController,
            muscleGroup = it.arguments?.getString(MUSCLE_GROUP_KEY).toString(),
            viewModel = viewModel,
            exerciseListFromDb = exerciseListFromDb
        )
    }

    composable(
        route = Screen.Add.route,
        arguments = listOf(navArgument(MUSCLE_GROUP_KEY) {
            type = NavType.StringType
        })
    ) {
        AddScreen(
            navController = navController, muscleGroup = it.arguments?.getString(MUSCLE_GROUP_KEY).toString(),
            viewModel = viewModel
        )
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I have a blog post here that explains it: https://www.francescvilarino.com/passing-arguments-to-screens-in-jetpack-compose

But basically you have to retrieve the arguments in the viewmodel from the `SavedStateHandle`, using the `key` that you used in your route for each argument.

```
navController.navigate(buildTwoRoute(argument))
```

then

```
@HiltViewModel
class TwoViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
    val argument = savedStateHandle.get<String>(DestinationOneArg).orEmpty()
    }
}
```

Comment: I've checked your blog and did everything as described and i don't have viewModel.state property to pass to Screen. Then even though I declared a variable inside ViewModel's init block i cant' access it from Screen, and by the way you've never shown how to do it, could you?

Comment: Please check this sample project: https://github.com/fvilarino/Weather-Sample/blob/03264d4d0d58ca0520d78b8087dafcec621e5e1c/presentation/feature/weather/src/main/java/com/francescsoftware/weathersample/feature/weather/viewmodel/WeatherViewModel.kt

Comment: Can instantiate the viewmodel in main activity and then pass it to navgraph as argument and then to other screens as argument, or do i have to instantiate it within navgraph by each screen composable every single time?

Comment: anyway, your answer seems to advanced for me. The sample project you've sent me is complicated a lot.

Comment: You have to use the hilt navigation artifact in Jetpack Compose to have the wiring in place out of the box, and then you need to instantiate the viewmodel in the nav graph; doing so ensures that the navigation arguments are available to the viewmodel in the SavedStateHandle.